# Running Android app in PiP mode

Tags: google-tv

Is it possible to put Google TV Android app in PiP mode (not full screen)?
I think this would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the only app that is able to run in PiP mode on Google TV is the "Live TV" app.  We've passed the feature request on to the Google TV product development team, and we'll definitely let the dev community know if/when it's part of a release!

**EDIT**

There's a feature request opened for this at:

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=13

If this is an important feature to you, add a star!

Answer (score 0):

In Android 8.0 oreo, they support the custom pip mode now. The document is here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html

Not only works for the tv devices but also mobile devices.